# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined jquery.validate.min.js:29

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined jquery.validate.min.js:29" when i am using the below code , the same code is working in "jquery-1.8.2.js" but its not working in "jquery-190.js" and if i remove "require_from_group: [1,".customer-identifier"]," from the validation its working.

```
$(document).on( 'pageinit', '#contact-us-page', function(event){

    var $currentPage = $(event.target);
    var $form = $currentPage.find("form#customer-identifier");
    var validator_contactuspage = $form.validate({  
    rules: {            
            account_number: {require_from_group: [1,".customer-identifier"], digits: true, maxlength: 10, minlength: 10},
            phone_number: {require_from_group: [1,".customer-identifier"], phoneUS: true}
        },
        messages: {
            account_number: {
                maxlength: "Please enter exactly 10 digits.",
                minlength: "Please enter exactly 10 digits."
            }
        },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).removeClass("valid");
            $(element).addClass("error");
        },
        success: function(element, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass("error");
            $(element).addClass("valid");

        },
        submitHandler: function(form){          
            getAddress();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $form.find("input[name=account_number]").bind("keyup change blur", function(event){
        if(checkNull($(this).val()).length > 0){
            $form.find("input[name=phone_number]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else{
            $form.find("input[name=phone_number]").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

    $form.find("input[name=phone_number]").bind("keyup change blur", function(event){
        if(checkNull(stripAlpha($(this).val())).length > 0){
            $form.find("input[name=account_number]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else{
            $form.find("input[name=account_number]").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Edit : I added my code on JSFiddle , if any body wants to give it a try.
http://jsfiddle.net/D65WY/36/

any thoughts?

Comment: Use the un-minified version and see what the actual problem is

Comment: I get this error after changing to unminfied version -       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined jquery.validate.js:503
$.extend.check jquery.validate.js:503
$.extend.checkForm jquery.validate.js:345
$.extend.form jquery.validate.js:333
$.extend.validate jquery.validate.js:81
st.event.dispatch jquery-190.js:2
st.event.add.y.handle jquery-190.js:2

Comment: Issue is resolved , I was using the "jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0" once i changed it to "jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.10.0" everything is working. so the addmethod for "require_from_group" is missing in the 1.9.0. sorry for false alaram.

Comment: This can be due to a bug in jquery.validation < 1.1.11

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678839/jquery-validator-cannot-call-method-call-of-undefined-error-while-adding-v