# JQuery form validation disables whole JQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

J Query form validation disables whole JQuery Code.I made a simple validation form using J Query. It's not working. 
i have tried   http://jsfiddle.net/4PuJL/165/ and working fine, but not working on my computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="http://http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#p1").mousedown(function () {
            alert("Mouse down over p1!");
        });       
        $("#personDetailForm").validate({
            rules: {
                persname: {
                    required: true,
                    regex: /^[A-Za-z]+$/
                }
            }
            submitHandler: function() {                        
                alert("alert");
            }
        });        
    });
    </script>
   </head>
 <body>        
  <p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
  <form id="personDetailForm" action="showDetails.html" method="post"  novalidate="novalidate" >
  <p>
    Name:
  <input type="text" name="persname" id="persname" maxlength="50"></p><br>
  Password:
  <input type="password" name="perspswd" id="perspswd"><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
  </form>
  <span></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

if i remove below part,then first alert starts working

```
$("#personDetailForm").validate({
  rules: {
  persname: {
  required: true,
  regex: /^[A-Za-z]+$/
  }
 }
 submitHandler: function() {                        
 alert("alert");
 }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery validator - Cannot call method 'call' of undefined error - while adding validation dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678839/jquery-validator-cannot-call-method-call-of-undefined-error-while-adding-v)

Comment: You should always check the console for errors. You have a missing `,` before the `submitHandler` property, and therefore a syntax error. And a wrong url here `http://http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually three problems...

1. Your script include for this plugin erroneously has `http://` written out twice.

   ```
   src="http://http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"
   ```
2. There is no such rule called `regex`.  If you include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js), then you can use the `pattern` method in its place.
3. You are missing a comma after the `rules` option...

   ```
   rules: {
       persname: {
           required: true,
           pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/  // <- use 'pattern' in place of "regex"
       }
   }, // <- need a comma here
   submitHandler: function() {                        
       alert("alert");
   }
   ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/c6L3Loot/**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#personDetailForm").validate({
   rules: {
      persname: {
         required: true,
         regex: /^[A-Za-z]+$/
      }
   }
   submitHandler: function() {                        
      alert("alert");
   }
});
```

Should be a `,` between `rules` and `submitHandler`.

You don't have the `submitHandler` part in your fiddle, that's why it's working.

Comment: Glad to help. Welcome to stackoverflow! :) If an answer has helped you please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your `<head>` section.

You are including this:

```
<script src="http://http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Which is wrong.
Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```